# Task vs Thread differences

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

There are two classes available in .NET: `Task` and `Thread`.

- What is the difference between those classes?
- When is it better to use `Thread` over `Task` (and vice-versa)?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: Prefer Task unless you need thread. Thread need resources(1MB stack(in .net commited), thread kernel object, etc). Task's are also run parallely as separate thread but it is a system thread pool threads that are optimized by the system considering cpu cores, etc and is used to run many tasks across system. Other than this the task when completed can return an object, so there is convinient way to know what the result of parallel execution is.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam When you say "system", are you referring to the .NET framework?

Comment: While this is an interesting read, @MoonKnight, reading a book about threading is a bit of an overkill for a SO question.

Comment: @TsahiAsher it is a single chapter _from_ a book.

Comment: I can't believe the most upvoted answer has been deleted (I can see it b/c of my big reputation). And there's no way to let mods know they made a mistake

Answer (score 538, accepted):

`Thread` is a lower-level concept: if you're directly starting a thread, you *know* it will be a separate thread, rather than executing on the thread pool etc.

`Task` is more than just an abstraction of "where to run some code" though - it's really just "the promise of a result in the future". So as some different examples:

- `Task.Delay` doesn't need any actual CPU time; it's just like setting a timer to go off in the future
- A task returned by `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` won't take much CPU time locally; it's representing a result which is likely to spend most of its time in network latency or remote work (at the web server)
- A task returned by `Task.Run()` really *is* saying "I want you to execute this code separately"; the exact thread on which that code executes depends on a number of factors.

Note that the `Task<T>` abstraction is pivotal to the async support in C# 5.

In general, I'd recommend that you use the higher level abstraction wherever you can: in modern C# code you should rarely need to explicitly start your own thread.

Comment: Even if you are running a message loop-like process you would use a task instead of a thread?

Comment: @SoMoS: Probably - you can create it as "long-running" and it will end up with a dedicated thread, but it means using a single abstraction throughout.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also , it's worth to mention that in asp.net - `new Thread()` is not dealing with Threadpool thread , whereas `Task` does use threadpool thread — http://i.stack.imgur.com/O8AnU.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's not really an ASP.NET-specific thing - and in some cases when you start a task it might use a non-thread-pool thread, if you specify that it's going to be a long-running task.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you please point out a few examples when you actually need to start your own thread in modern C#?

Comment: @Leonid: Not offhand... It does avoid the task scheduler needing to get involved at all... But yes, these days I'd stick to Task.Run.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev: Not directly Task related (this was before Tasks were introduced), but I did starve the thread pool once doing some image analysis work. I was using (too many really) the thread pool for object detection, but was pushing the results using an SDK which also used the threadpool. This caused my program to lock up because all threads were busy.

Comment: What if I want to use `Task` in realtime system,I need to pause and resume,cancel and stop,does `Task` works even in that harsh cirmustance?

Comment: @zionpi: No, `Task` has no concept of pausing.

Comment: Task is a poor man thread. Running task in same thread as it was called from is not what a high throughput low latency server developer would use ever.

Answer (score 55):

Usually you hear *Task is a higher level concept than thread*... and that's what this phrase means:

1. You can't use Abort/ThreadAbortedException, you should support
   cancel event in your "business code" periodically testing `token.IsCancellationRequested` flag (also avoid long or timeoutless connections e.g. to db, otherwise you will never get a chance to test this flag). By the similar reason `Thread.Sleep(delay)` call should be replaced with  `Task.Delay(delay, token)` call (passing token inside to have possibility to interrupt delay).
2. There are no thread's `Suspend` and `Resume` methods functionality with tasks. **Instance of task can't be reused** either.
3. But you get two new tools:

   a) **continuations**

   ```
   // continuation with ContinueWhenAll - execute the delegate, when ALL
   // tasks[] had been finished; other option is ContinueWhenAny

   Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll( 
      tasks,
      () => {
          int answer = tasks[0].Result + tasks[1].Result;
          Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", answer);
      }
   );
   ```

   b) **nested/child tasks**

   ```
   //StartNew - starts task immediately, parent ends whith child
   var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew
   (() => {
             var child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
            //...
            });
         },  
         TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
   );
   ```
4. So system thread is completely hidden from task, but still task's code is executed in the concrete system thread. **System threads are resources for tasks** and ofcourse there is still thread pool under the hood of task's parallel execution. There can be different strategies how thread get new tasks to execute. Another shared resource **TaskScheduler** cares about it. Some problems that **TaskScheduler** solves 1) prefer to execute task and its conitnuation in the same thread minimizing switching cost - aka *inline execution*) 2) prefer execute tasks in an order they were started - aka *PreferFairness* 3) more effective distribution of tasks between inactive threads depending on "prior knowledge of tasks activity"  - aka *Work Stealing*. Important: in general "async" is not same as "parallel". Playing with TaskScheduler options you can setup async tasks be executed in one thread synchronously. To express parallel code execution higher abstractions (than Tasks) could be used: [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library), [`PLINQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq), [`Dataflow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).
5. Tasks are integrated with C# async/await features aka **Promise Model**, e.g there `requestButton.Clicked += async (o, e) => ProcessResponce(await client.RequestAsync(e.ResourceName));` the execution of `client.RequestAsync` will not block UI thread. Important: under the hood `Clicked` delegate call is absolutely regular (all threading is done by compiler).

That is enough to make a choice. If you need to support Cancel functionality of calling legacy API that tends to hang (e.g. timeoutless connection) and for this case supports Thread.Abort(), or if you are creating multithread background calculations and want to optimize switching between threads using Suspend/Resume, that means to manage parallel execution manually - stay with Thread. Otherwise go to Tasks because of they will give you easy manipulate on groups of them, are integrated into the language and make developers more productive - [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) .

Comment: Note - `Thread.Abort` doesn't work for most long operations like DB connections either. It can only abort while in managed code, while most of the long-waiting stuff is stuck in native code (e.g. waiting for a handle, I/O operations...). The only benefit is that it can abort *anywhere* in managed code, relatively safely (e.g. not in `finally` clauses etc.), so it will help against errors like infinite loops etc. Using it in production-level code doesn't make much sense, though.

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is evil and should be avoided wherever possible. Code running under the possibility of a thread abort is incredibly difficult to reason about correctly. It's not worth it, just check some kind of flag. (I'd suggest the `CancellationToken` API, even if you're not using Tasks)

Comment: It's an error to do so _`Thread.Sleep(delay)` should be replaced with `Task.Delay(delay, token);`_ If, then it should  be replaced with `Task.Delay(delay, token).Wait();`, which is the same as `Thread.Sleep(delay)`, or with `await Task.Delay(delay, token)`, if it is possible.

Answer (score 43):

The [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is used for creating and manipulating a [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows.

A [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task) represents some asynchronous operation and is part of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a set of APIs for running tasks asynchronously and in parallel.

In the days of old (i.e. before TPL) it used to be that using the `Thread` class was one of the standard ways to run code in the background or in parallel (a better alternative was often to use a [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)), however this was cumbersome and had several disadvantages, not least of which was the performance overhead of creating a whole new thread to perform a task in the background.

Nowadays using tasks and the TPL is a far better solution 90% of the time as it provides abstractions which allows far more efficient use of system resources.  I imagine there are a few scenarios where you want explicit control over the thread on which you are running your code, however generally speaking if you want to run something asynchronously your first port of call should be the TPL.