# C#. Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have two threads. First of them implements two methods, second only one. I need to synchronize threads this way: implementation of first method from first thread, implementation of method from second thread, implementation of second method from first thread. I tried to use barrier but it doesn't help:

```
bool complete = false;

// Start tasks
Task task_1 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    if (complete)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }
});

Task task_2 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
});
task_2.Wait();
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Thank you for all your posts. I tried to use `barrier` class but the result is not which I need. I will try to explain my problem. I have few threads in which are called two or more methods:

```
 Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2); // 2 = #threads participating.
            bool complete = false;
            TaskFactory factory = Task.Factory;

            // Start tasks
            Task task_1 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                process_1.Server("1 and 2");
                barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 2 to catch up.
                barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 2 to print "2" and set complete = true.

                if (complete)
                {
                    process_1.Server("1 and 3");
                }
            });
            Task task_6 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                process_6.Server("6 and 4");
                process_6.Server("6 and 3");
            });
            Task task_2 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 1 to print "1".
                process_2.Client("1 and 2");
                complete = true;
                barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 1 to read complete as true.

                process_2.Server("2 and 5");
                process_2.Server("2 and 3");
            });
            Task task_4 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                process_4.Client("6 and 4");
                process_4.Server("4 and 7");
                process_4.Server("4 and 3");
            });
            Task task_5 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                process_5.Client("2 and 5");
                process_5.Server("5 and 3");
            });
            Task task_7 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                process_7.Client("4 and 7");
                process_7.Server("7 and 3");
            });
            Task task_3 = factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                process_3.Client("1 and 3");
                process_3.Client("2 and 3");
                process_3.Client("4 and 3");
                process_3.Client("5 and 3");
                process_3.Client("6 and 3");
                process_3.Client("7 and 3");
            });

            task_3.Wait();
```

I need to ensure consequence between calling methods from different threads for example: `process_1.Server("1 and 2");` and `process_2.Client("1 and 2");`. Calling Client method before Server is not acceptable. All the dependencies: {process_1.Server("1 and 2"); process_2.Client("1 and 2");}, {process_2.Server("2 and 5"); process_5.Client("2 and 5");}, {process_6.Server("6 and 4"); process_4.Client("6 and 4");}, {process_4.Server("4 and 7"); process_7.Client("4 and 7");}, {process_1.Server("1 and 3"); process_3.Client("1 and 3");}, {process_2.Server("2 and 3"); process_3.Client("2 and 3");}, {process_4.Server("4 and 3"); process_3.Client("4 and 3");}, {process_5.Server("5 and 3"); process_3.Client("5 and 3");}, {process_6.Server("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3");}, {process_7.Server("7 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3");}.

Between elemets {...} and {...} there are no dependecies. So it is possible to execute {process_6.Server("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3");}, {process_7.Server("7 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3");} or vice versa {process_7.Server("7 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3");}, {process_6.Server("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3");}. There are dependencies between elements into {...} which I wrote. Can you help me to solve this problem? I can not figure out how to implement this. Thank you very much!

Comment: what do you mean by implementation? Implementation is writing code...

Comment: I think OP wants to Wrtie 1,2,3 in order

Comment: Why not write actual methods? This seems harder.

Comment: yes, I want to write 1, 2, 3. But now 1, 3, 2 or something else

Comment: I don't see any point of this code logic. Why don't you simply call all your methods in desired order from a single task? The result will be exactly a same as all three methods will never run at a same time.

Comment: @HABJAN, this makes a pretty good exercise for understanding thread synchronization and out of order execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)

```
AutoResetEvent waitA = new AutoResetEvent(false); //task_1 uses this to signal task_2
AutoResetEvent waitB = new AutoResetEvent(false); //task_2 uses this to signal task_1

// Start tasks
Task task_1 = Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("1");
                   waitA.Set();
                   waitB.WaitOne();
                   Console.WriteLine("3");
               });

Task task_2 = Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   waitA.WaitOne();
                   Console.WriteLine("2");
                   waitB.Set();
               });
task_2.Wait();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rnfWRZ

Comment: @user3649515 the answer by Matthew Watson is a far better solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The language will execute methods in order natively, take advantage of this and refactor your code

```
        bool complete = false;

        // Start tasks
        Task task_1 = factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Console.WriteLine("2");

            if (complete)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("3");
            }

            complete = true;
        });

        task_1.Wait();
```

Synchronization hacks will obfuscate your code's intent. Avoid where you can!

Comment: I understand. I need to commenicate between threads and need synchronization. I posted an example similar to my programm. What mechanism I should use to execute first method from first thread, method from second thread, second method from first thread?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the threads to output "1, 2, 3" you can do it like this:

```
Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2); // 2 = #threads participating.
bool complete = false;

// Start tasks
Task task_1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 2 to catch up.
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 2 to print "2" and set complete = true.
    if (complete)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }
});

Task task_2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 1 to print "1".
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    complete = true;
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 1 to read complete as true.
});

task_2.Wait();
```

Comment: MSDN assigns the `Barrier` class specifically for this use - `Enables multiple tasks to cooperatively work on an algorithm in parallel through multiple phases.`

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing task  with  thread as many  tasks  can  use the some thread. 
from  [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences) answer

1. Thread is a lower-level concept: if you're directly starting a thread, you know it will be a separate thread, rather than executing on the thread pool etc.
2. Task is more than just an abstraction of "where to run some code" though - it's really just "the promise of a result in the future".

And  `MemoryBarrier` is needed for the compiler to stop the reorder of instructions as compiler can decide to do optimisations.

you  can  do  something  like this to  achieve the execution in the order

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = new TaskFactory().StartNew(Method1);
        var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(delegate { Method2(); });
        var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(delegate { Method1(); });

    }

    private static void Method1()
    {

    }
    private static void Method2()
    {


    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner and only try to uderstand multithreading