# What happens when you create a Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
public MyClass foo(int parameter)
{
    var foo = new Task<MyClass>(() => bar(parameter));

    try 
    {
        return foo.Result;
    }
}
```

What happens in terms of threads when I create a `new Task`.

That means that new thread(`B`) started to evaluate `bar(parameter)` and when the main thread(`A`) goes to  `foo.Result;` they wait until `B` finish and return `Result`?

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on the web about tasks. Try searching. :)

Comment: Nothing happens. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html

Comment: @Vadim holy shit that's a bad article. _"[Tasks] support a piece of code to run in parallel processors. It just simply spawns threads into multiple processes"_ - ehm...

Comment: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/9/5B924336-AA5D-4903-95A0-56C6336E32C9/TAP.docx

Comment: I does not look like it will run until you call Run() method anyway.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of some question (I couldn't find one quickly, though), but it's not a duplicate of the "what's the difference between thread and task".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OP is explicitly asking whether a task starts a new thread, which was explained in that duplicate. Why reopen and upvote a question that gets asked daily and shows no research? Anyway see [Task vs Thread differences \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/), [What is the difference between task and thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/), [MSDN: The Managed Thread Pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx), [MSDN: Task Schedulers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402(v=vs.110).aspx) and so on.

Comment: "What happens in terms of threads when I create a new `Task`?" Nothing. The new `Task` object gets created inactive. If you do not do anything else with the `foo` object, `bar` is never called.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So `foo` its just an instance of `Task`. I need to call `Start()` inside of `try` and only after that we started to evaluate `bar` and when we finish we will can return `Result`

Comment: Nothing happens - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs,136

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/9/5B924336-AA5D-4903-95A0-56C6336E32C9/TAP.docx):

> Tasks created by its public constructors are referred to as “cold”
>   tasks, in that they begin their life cycle in the non-scheduled
>   TaskStatus.Created state, and it’s not until Start is called on these
>   instances that they progress to being scheduled

Thus, no "thread B" will be started (moreover, "*start* new task" != "*start* new thread" in the general case).

> and when the main thread(A) goes to foo.Result; they wait until B finish and return Result?

Since there will be no "thread B", thread A will wait forever.

Comment: So I need to call `foo.Start()` == start to evaluate `bar`. And when it will finish we will return `foo.Result`

Comment: Either to call `Start`, or create new "hot" task (using `Task.Run`) instead of "cold" one. There must be a significant reason to create cold tasks.

Comment: Can you explain me please why I don't have a `Run` method, just `RunSynchronously`, `Start`, `Wait` and others...?

Comment: oh, I understand, I need to write `Task.Run(() => foo(parameter)); ` Am I right? But if I want to "run" my `foo` instance that I created previously ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Task.Run` for create new task, `foo.Start` to start created "cold" task.

Comment: Do I need to call `foo.Wait()` after `foo.Start()` or I can `return foo.Result`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx: "it is equivalent to calling the Wait method". What prevents you from reading docs?