# Async method does not return Actual Data in asmx

Tags: c#, web-services

I have below Method in `ASMX` Service :

```
 [WebMethod]
    public  async Task<DataSet> GetDetailAsync(int id)
    {
        var result =await _oService.GetDetailAsync(id);

        return myService.ToDataSet(result);
    }
```

but The result is :

```
<TaskOfDataSet/>
```

how can I solve this ? I've searched but I couldn't find anything similar question or issue .

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622372/is-there-some-way-to-handle-async-await-behind-an-asmx-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Webservice: Webmethod, that calls an async method, returns Taskoff object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181107/c-sharp-webservice-webmethod-that-calls-an-async-method-returns-taskoff-objec)