# How to start two parallel threads from one object?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let's say I have an object with one method that is constantly running.
I already created a new thread running this method:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(myObject.firstMethod)).Start();
```

Now, I have a `secondMethod` in `myObject` that I want to start.
Keep in mind that the previously strarted thread isn't terminated because `firstMethod` contains a Loop.

How can I start the second method? Do I need to create a second Thread?

Comment: `new Thread(new ThreadStart(myObject.secondMethod)).Start();`? If `secondMethod` can run independently from `firstMethod`

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Yes but only if they can run completely independently and parallely. (See @DmitryBychenko 's answer.) Otherwise use a single thread with a new method that runs both methods synchronously, calling first one, then the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its kind of unclear what you are asking or what you are exactly trying to achieve, however here is an example using `Task` running 2 endless loops (until a cancellation token is called)

```
public static void Method1(CancellationToken token)
{
      Task.Run(
         async () =>
         {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
               // do something
               await Task.Delay(500, token); // <- await with cancellation
               Console.WriteLine("Method1");
            }
         }, token);
}

public static void Method2(CancellationToken token)
{
      Task.Run(
         async () =>
            {
               while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                  // do something
                  await Task.Delay(300, token); // <- await with cancellation
                  Console.WriteLine("Method2");
               }
            }, token);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var source = new CancellationTokenSource();  
   Method1(source.Token);
   Method2(source.Token);
   source.CancelAfter(3000);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pp8M8V)

---

[Task vs Thread differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences)

> `Thread` is a lower-level concept: if you're directly starting a
>   thread, you *know* it will be a separate thread, rather than executing
>   on the thread pool etc.
>
> `Task` is more than just an abstraction of "where to run some code"
>   though - it's really just "the promise of a result in the future". So
>   as some different examples:
>
> - `Task.Delay` doesn't need any actual CPU time; it's just like setting a timer to go off in the future
> - A task returned by `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` won't take much CPU time locally; it's representing a result which is likely to
>     spend most of its time in network latency or remote work (at the web
>     server)
> - A task returned by `Task.Run()` really *is* saying "I want you to execute this code separately"; the exact thread on which that code
>     executes depends on a number of factors.
>
> Note that the `Task<T>` abstraction is pivotal to the async support in
>   C# 5.
>
> In general, I'd recommend that you use the higher level abstraction
>   wherever you can: in modern C# code you should rarely need to
>   explicitly start your own thread.

Quote [Jon Skeet](http://Jon%20Skeet)

Comment: It is not obvious that Tasks would be better here. Also note that Console.WriteLine() is one of those rare methods that is 'thread-safe'.

Comment: @bommelding You are right about the Task, ill update