# Synchronization context for Task.Delay

Tags: c#, .net, task, synchronizationcontext

I could find out that, `Task.Run` executes always on threads from .NET Framework threads pool (`TaskScheduler.Default`). I suppose, that it is the same with `Task.Delay`, but I'm not sure.

MSDN says for [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.2) only:

> Creates a task that will complete after a time delay

Therefore the **question:** Where (in which synchronization context) runs `Task.Delay`?

Comment: Have a look at [Task vs Thread differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences). *"(A Task) it's really just "the promise of a result in the future""*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Delay` *doesn't run anywhere*.  It just creates a task that completes after the specified time.  Unlike `Task.Run` it's not accepting a delegate of yours to run somewhere.  Most tasks won't represent the execution of some method on another thread.  `Task.Run` is one of few methods that do that.

Comment: For it completes after specified time, it should run specified time, or?

Comment: @Rekshino It's not "running" anything.  It's creating a task that will be marked as completed after the specified time.  It's not sitting there running code during that time.  It's *doing nothing* during that time.

Comment: I'm reminded of a [recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376516/can-asp-net-run-background-tasks-simultaneously?noredirect=1#comment93629380_53376516) :)

Comment: @Servy Hmm.. I need to think about Wait() and await for `Task.Delay` for task, which does not run.

Comment: @Liam The OP here can't see that as it's deleted, but yes.

Comment: @Rekshino It's almost always wrong to synchronously block on a task.  All the moreso when that task is `Delay`.

Comment: @Servy But Task.Delay(N).Wait() block our synchronisation context right?

Comment: @Rekshino Yes.  And that's basically never correct.  It's the waiting that does the blocking, not the `Delay`.

Comment: @Servy Can we say, that Task.Delay is an "empty" Task, which being finished in N ms and running in synchronisation context where it is called?

Comment: @Rekshino No, you can't say that it's "running in the synchronization context where it's called" because **it's not running anywhere**.  `Task.Delay` doesn't involve running code.  It creates a task that will be completed at the specified time *and does not involve any code running during that interval of time*.

Comment: @Servy Now.. I have understood! :) I have voted up the key comment. May be it makes sense to copy it to the answer.