# Propagate a callback onto a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, closures

I've a question about `multithreading` in **C#**.

Let's suppose we have this interface

```
public interface IMyCallback
{
    void OnSum(int a, int b, int result);
}
```

Then I've another class, that has a list of `IMyCallback`as private field

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IList<IMyCallback> _Subscribers = new List<IMyCallback>();
    
    public void Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        int result = a + b;
        foreach (IMyCallback subscriber in _Subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.OnSum(a, b, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Pratically what it does is doing a sum between two numbers and notify all the service subscribers that it has performed the arithmetic operation `a + b` and the result is *result*.

Now I want to improve the performance and send each notification onto a **Thread**. What I usually do to avoid enclosure and memory problem with compiler is this:

```
public void Sum (int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    foreach (IMyCallback subscriber in _Subscribers)
    {
         new Thread((o) =>
         {
             object[] state = (object[])o;

             ((IMyCallback)state[0])
                   .OnSum((int)state[1], (int)state[2], (int)state[3]
         })
         {
             IsBackground = true
         }
         .Start(new object[] { subscriber, a, b, result });

    }
}
```

I want to focus the attention on the last part, when I pass all the parameters into an array of object and use it into the delegate. Am I doing correct? Is it a correct pattern or there are some issues I cannot understand?

Comment: The only thing I don't like 100% is spawning off a thread for each Subscriber. What if you ended up with 1000 subscribers? Have you looked into TPL? For example: `Parallel.ForEach()`? BTW: The way you are passing objects to the thread is perfectly fine (my opinion).

Comment: C# offers some higher level constructs to deal with these. An `event` for example is a multicast delegate which would allow you to avoid the loop to begin with, and a `Task` is [generally preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429164/2791540) over creating threads on your own. Do you have specific reasons for avoiding these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a comment to your question, but will try to reiterate what I was saying. Firstly: the question about passing an array of parameters as a generic object is perfectly fine. Because that method is the only method consuming that generic object array, it makes perfect sense.

The one thing that I am slightly concerned about is how you are spawning threads. If you have 10,000 subscribers, it's going to be rough on the ol' CPU. Since you are currently using synchronous code, I would use a `Parallel.ForEach()` on your subscribers.

```
public void Sum (int a, int b)
{
    var result = a + b;
    Parallel.ForEach (_Subscribers, subscriber =>
    {
        subscriber.OnSum(a,b,result);
    });
}
```

The advantage to this is you the the framework decide how many threads it needs to finish your job. If you have 5 subscribers or 10,000 -- it won't kill your CPU.

The beauty of this code as well is, if `OnSum` throws an exception, the caller will actually get it. With your current method, all exceptions will be lost forever.

ETA:
Now, if you'd like to use async/await and `Task`, this is one way to *safely* do it:

```
public Task SumAsync (int a, int b)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(_Subscribers.Select(x=> Task.Run(() =>
    {
        x.OnSum(a, b, a + b);
    })));
}
```

This will also catch/throw all exceptions. I do *not* like this solution as it's not organically asynchronous. I like the use of `Parallel.ForEach()` for this solution.